# wsdl 2.0 support in PHP

Tags: php, wsdl

If I want to create a web service or consume a web service that is defined as WSDL 2.0, what options do I have in PHP?

As I understand it the in-built SOAP libs in 5.x don't currently support WSDL 2.0 spec, and I can't see future support for this.

Answer (score 1):

One of my former colleagues used to devour SOAP services manually, simply because he disliked the current .net implementation.

The SOAP implementation is based around you posting XML across the web to the service, and you "just" need to build a such XML and parse the results coming back. It is not as simple as it sounds, but it definitely is possible.

The [WSDL2PHP](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2phpgenerator/) project seems very interesting, and im very sure this can lead you in the right direction.